# Shifting columns in Dataframe with unordered index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, shift

I have a pandas datafrrame with many rows, indexed by a PeriodIndex. What I need to do is to add a column, with data coming from some other columns, but shifted in time.

For this reason, I understand that I have to use either the shift or tshift methods. However, I have a complication: I am not sure whether the index is sorted or not. I cannot check this because actually the operation I am performing is within a groupby function (to be specific: the ORIGINAL index is not sorted by date, however within each group of the groupby method it should be - however I am not 100% sure).

In short, I want to be sure that the additional column takes data from the original column one period before - which may not coincide with the row above. I also want that no additional rows are created (for the period after the last among the original ones).

Below are three methods that I tried, which give the same output and seems to work.

```
In [1]:  df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4], index=pd.to_datetime([2011, 2012, 2010, 2013], format='%Y').to_period(freq='Y'))

In [2]:  df
Out[2]:
      0
2011  1
2012  2
2010  3
2013  4

In [3]: df['A'] = df.loc[:,0].shift(freq='Y')

In [4]: df['B'] = df.loc[:,0].tshift(1)

In [5]: df['C'] = df.loc[:,0].tshift(freq='Y')

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
      0    A    B    C
2011  1  3.0  3.0  3.0
2012  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2010  3  NaN  NaN  NaN
2013  4  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

However, are these three methods truly equivalent? If not, which is the correct one to use? If yes, is any of these preferable for some reasons compared to the others?

Comment: Pick the one that works? In this case, they all work, so probably time them and pick the fastest?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, probably I was not 100% clear: from this example it seems to me that they all work fine, however maybe there are some issues that may arise, or tricks I am not aware of

Comment: Such a question should then be asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as there is no error or undesired results to troubleshoot here.